# Error with command 'flutter doctor' in my Terminal

Tags: flutter, terminal

For 2 days now have I tried to install Flutter. But every time I come to the Terminal part I get a error. I have watched many video's looked online for a solution. But I couldend find anything. If someone can help me with this problem I would be very grateful.
[Screenshot of the error I encounter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNEMn.png)

Comment: Add flutter path to Environment Variables under PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

have you insert flutter path to your environment ?

Comment: Yes I have. I have ones again followed a video and added it to my path.
Videolink if you want to see how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ekT-SpKrgk
At around 3.50 he did that part.

Comment: After waiting for around 30min en trying the command again it works. So this question is solved. But thank you for trying to help!